# Geofecncing in flutter?

Tags: flutter, location, geofencing

My application uses geofencing, it shows notifications when the phone enters certain areas (geofences). Code works perfectly fine when phone is unlocked.
how to add geofencing in flutter app when the phone is locked and app is in foreground?
.....

Comment: Show your code and explain what's not working. Please edit your post and add more context and information.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.